# Example Decorator Error

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand Python decorators and have written this code:

```
def hello_world(fn):
    print('hello world')
    fn()
    pass

@hello_world
def decorate():
    print('hello decoatrion')
    return

decorate()
```

I was aiming to print 'hello world' before 'hello decoration', but the output is the following:

```
hello world
hello decoatrion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_decortor.py", line 11, in <module>
    decorate()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: OK, so what's your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Comment: Your decorator is returning `None`, not the decorated function. Check out [these examples](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods), as well as [PEP 318 - Decorators for Functions, Methods and Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorator syntax is shorthand for

```
decorated = decorate(decorated)
```

So if you have:

```
def hello_world(fn):
    print('hello world')
    fn()
    pass

def decorate():
    print('hello decoatrion')
    return

decorate = hello_world(decorate)
```

You should see what the problem is (also note that `pass` does nothing here).

```
def hello_world(fn):
    def says_hello():
        print('hello world')
        return fn()
    return says_hello

def decorate():
    print('hello decoration')

decorate = hello_world(decorate)
```

will do what you want. Or you could write it:

```
@hello_world
def decorate():
    print('hello decoration')
```

Comment: Documentation reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Answer (score 3):

The decorator must **return the decorated function**. You probably wanted something along these lines:

```
def hello_world(fn):
    def inner():
        print('hello world')
        fn()
    return inner

@hello_world
def decorate():
    print('hello decoatrion')
    return

decorate()
#output: hello world
#        hello decoatrion
```